# Trying to detect an ActiveX plugin

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, activex

I am trying to detect the presence of an ActiveX plugin in my website. I am currently using:

```
function PrepareForBuyMallMoneyWithFBCredits(){
   try {
   control = new ActiveXObject('ActiveX name');
   } catch (e) {
   alert('fail');
   }
   alert(control);
  }
```

I have confirmed that this code works against more standard ActiveX controls such as Adobe Acrobat Reader but I am trying to detect a custom ActiveX control. Problem is, the name that comes up in the plugin browser doesn't seem to be the one I should be searching for. Is there some way for me to find out what/where this name is? Also, is it possible to use the classid to achieve my desired results? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Usually you'll find this name inside the win-registry.

Example for flash:

- Go in IE to **tools->manage addons**
- You'll find there an entry "**Shockwave Flash Object**"(thats the friendly name of the plugin)
- remember this name and go to the registry
- open the search-box inside the registry, type in this friendly name and check only the box "data"
- the search should find in **HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT** an key with a classId as name
  (e.g. **{HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID{D27CDB70-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000}**)
- inside this key should be a sub-key named "**progId**"
- open this key, it should have a standard-value(e.g. **ShockwaveFlash.ShockwaveFlash.10**)
- this standard-value is what you'll have to use as plugin-name inside your script.